# How to create a simple Button with output in a python jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Trying to create a simple button with some output I tried the following code

```
from IPython.display import display
def clicked():
    print("button has been clicked!")

button_download = widgets.Button(description = 'Test Button')   
button_download.on_click(clicked)
display(button_download)
```

but when I click on the button I cannot see any output.

I found another example that works, but this is way too complicated:

```
from IPython.display import display
button = widgets.Button(description="Click Me!")
output = widgets.Output()

display(button, output)

def on_button_clicked(b):
    with output:
        print("Button clicked.")

button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
```

Do I really need to `output` thing so I can see the output of a `print` statement when I click the button?

The system is Jupyterlab 1.1.4.

Answer (score 7):

You only need to add an argument to the `clicked` function to make it work:

```
from IPython.display import display
import ipywidgets as widgets


def clicked(arg):
    print("button has been clicked!")

button_download = widgets.Button(description = 'Test Button')   
button_download.on_click(clicked)
display(button_download)
```

Comment: I copied your exact example, but it  does not seem to work. I do not se any output.

Comment: I just tested it on Jupyterlab 1.1.4. and it also outputs nothing. It works however on Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Yes might be, but I need it to work on jupyterlab. Sorry I did not post that info earlier...

Comment: I think you have to create the output widget then.

Comment: If this happens to be helpful, I restarted jupyter-lab from the terminal after installing ipywidgets and the button displayed, and the button displays; it works when there is no code currently running, and does not work when, say, there is a loop running. I am looking for a graceful way to exit a loop by clicking a button, would be great for ML experiments.